# jquery each item not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

My WebApi is returning the the following JSON object:

```
[
{
    "Department_Id": 5,
    "Department_Description": "Test API 1"
},
{
    "Department_Id": 6,
    "Department_Description": "Test API 2"
},
{
    "Department_Id": 7,
    "Department_Description": "Test API 3"
}
]
```

Within my web-form that uses asp.net, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/TicketDepartments/GetTicketDepartmentsComboBoxAsync",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var select = $("#ddlDepartment");

                if (data) {
                    $(data).each(function(index, item) {
                        select.append($(" 
<option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("An error has occurred during processing your 
 request.");
            }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

However, whenever I attempt to run the code, I get an `"item is not defined"` error.

I'm trying to populate

```
Select department :
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

with the department_description and the department_id so that is can be used later on within the program.

I'm unsure of what this error means or where it comes from. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.each()` method is used for looping through a jQuery collection that contains DOM elements. If you want to loop through an ordinary array or object, you should use the `$.each()` function.

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    ...
}
```

Also, the properties in your objects are `Department_ID` and `Department_Description`, not `Value` and `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be :

```
select.append($("<option>").val(item.Department_Id).text(item.Department_Description));
                    });
```

Comment: The error is complaining about `item`, not the property names.